# is ngx-http-client depricated in angular 16

Tags: angular

This is not direct code question, but related to libs used in coding.
As I'm in the middle of converting an old ( angular 9) app to angular 16
I'm trying to import `ngx-http-client`  by npm install into my prj.

Though it gives me lots of errors, i'm a bit surprised as i was used to think that ngx libs are bit more advanced giving some extra's as compared to angular buildin modules.
Might it be that that futures in the past are now available in into angular main (@angular/common/http) ?

WEll maybe someone knows, as my Angular project was really old and such discussions gets lost over time on the web.

I tried ofcourse to install it, made docker test environments etc but to no success.

Comment: Use [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-http-client) which says "Angular (4.3+) HttpClientModule" and "1.0.0-beta.5 • Public • Published 6 years ago" and "Weekly Downloads: 1" — Looks like it has been abandoned.

Comment: `ngx` is just a naming convention of  `angular extras` anyone can name his/her library starting with `ngx`, this won't make that library reliable, or official. Do you require some specific feature that standard angular HTTP library doesn't provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular v16 dropped the support for non-ivy (All pre v9 libs) libraries.

This is why you're getting an error in v16.

`@angular/common/http` is the way to go for Http requests. The support for [`fetch`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/withFetch) requests has been added recently.

Comment: Thanks i've dropped into an angular prj from which the original dev has gone.
So i'm fixing his never maintained prj's while a bit new to angular as well so i dont know the historic movements, and also i'm now cured of thinking that ngx was some kind of community brand trying to improve upon main branche.